# Python Round decimals using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, decimal, precision

this snippet works properly expect for the fact that the precision is not set. Outputs have many decimals after the comma, I want it to be set to 2. Tried many ways to set it but none of them have worked. Any ideas how I can reach this?

Many thanks.

```
def getExponential():

x2 = entry2.get()
label2 = Label(window, text=float(x2)*float(x2))
canvas1.create_window(350, 100, window=label2)

button2 = Button(text='Get the Exponential', command=getExponential)
canvas1.create_window(240, 100, window=button2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `format` your value, considerfollowing example:

```
sqrt2 = 2**0.5
print('{:.3f}'.format(sqrt2))
```

output

```
1.414
```

In your case just replace

```
label2 = Label(window, text=float(x2)*float(x2))
```

using

```
label2 = Label(window, text='{:.2f}'.format(float(x2)*float(x2)))
```

If you want to know more about `.format` usage read [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) or [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) in docs.